# Close dropdown on click anywhere

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the below code that works on clicking dropdowns and opening them, but then when I click on another dropdown, it doesn't close the previous one - How could I adjust my JS code to close the previous dropdown and keep the current dropdown open only?

```js
function dropdowns() {
    var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown:not(.is-hoverable)');

    if (dropdowns.length > 0) {
        dropdowns.forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                el.classList.toggle('is-active');
            });
        });

        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            closeDropdowns();
        });
    }

    function closeDropdowns() {
        dropdowns.forEach(function (el) {
            el.classList.remove('is-active');
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown is-clickable">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>Dropdown button</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        Dropdown item
      </a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">
        Other dropdown item
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item is-active">
        Active dropdown item
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        Other dropdown item
      </a>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
        With a divider
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First things first, when I click your button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `closeDropdowns()` before you toggle the `is-active` class in your event handler.

```
function dropdowns() {
    var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown:not(.is-hoverable)');

    if (dropdowns.length > 0) {
        dropdowns.forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();

                closeDropdowns(); // <== HERE
                el.classList.toggle('is-active');
            });
        });

        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            closeDropdowns();
        });
    }

    function closeDropdowns() {
        dropdowns.forEach(function (el) {
            el.classList.remove('is-active');
        });
    }
}
```

However, you should add a check to test if the dropdown is currently open and if so - skip the toggling of the class as this will close and reopen it again.

```
el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const isActive = el.classList.contains('is-active');

    closeDropdowns();

    if (!isActive) {
        el.classList.toggle('is-active'); // or simply el.classList.add('is-active');
    }
    
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @zhulien, works like a charm! I just had to move it above `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: How would you best add in a check?

Comment: @DevSem I've edited my post for easier visibility.

Comment: Man thank you so much! It works absolutely flawless.